# Grep "-C" command on all machine

Tags: linux, grep, aix, hp-ux, sunos

I am using `grep -C 1 "matching string" "xty.pom"`

This works on Linux machines, but the same code is not working on other platforms like AIX, SunOS_x64, HPUX.

Is there any alternative to this so that same code logic works on all the platforms?

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input, expected output and what you have tried so far so we can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will function like `grep -C 1 "matching string"` but should work on platforms that do not support grep's `-C` option:

```
awk '/matching string/{print last; f=2} f{print; f--} {last=$0}' File
```

#### How it works

- `/matching string/{print last; f=2}`

  If the current line matches the regex `matching string`, then print the previous line (which was saved in `last`) and set `f` to 2.
- `f{print; f--}`

  If `f` is nonzero, then print the current line and decrement `f`.
- `last=$0`

  Set `last` equal to the contents of the current line.

#### Improvement

With some minor changes, we can handle overlapping matches better:

```
awk '/a/{if (NR>1 && !f)print last; f=3} f>1{print} f{f--} {last=$0}'
```

As an example of output with an overlapping match:

```
$ printf '%s\n'   a a b |  awk '/a/{if (NR>1 && !f)print last; f=3} f>1{print} f{f--} {last=$0}'
a
a
b
```

#### Sun/Solaris

The native awk on Sun/Solaris is notoriously bug-filled.  Use instead `nawk` or
better yet `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`  or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk`

Comment: That awk command will only behave like `grep -C 1` when the regexp doesn't appear at the start of the file or on consecutive lines. Try searching for `a` in a file that contains `a\na\nb\n` (where `\n` is a literal newline) using `grep -C 1` and that awk command and note the grep outputs the file as-is (`a\na\nb\n`) while the awk outputs `\na\na\na\nb\n`.